# Can I force an extra run of a scheduled execution?

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a singleThreadExecutor that I'm feeding a Runnable with a scheduledFixedDelay like this

```
Runnable periodic = new Runnable() { ... }

ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(periodic, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

It will run with 1 minute delay between executions. Problem is, sometimes I need to run it "on demand". Is that possible?

I've thought about cancelling the execution, run the Runnable and restart the execution but what I would really like is some simple method thats just executes the Runnable a head of time and the reschedules it to run again in one minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want the task to run you can submit it

```
executor.submit(periodic);
```

or add it with a delay

```
executor.schedule(periodic, delay, units);
```

Comment: But if the executor already have this Runnable either executing or scheduled what will happen then?

Comment: It would be run both times you asked it to run.

Comment: While not exactly what I wanted I've approved of this answer. I'd really like it to do the *planned* execution now instead of when it was planned but it also works to add the periodic as a new one time job as I'm using a singleThreadScheduledExecutor.